# PHPMailer send base64 image

Tags: php, mysql, email, base64, phpmailer

I am attempting to email an image from a MySQL database via PHPMailer.

Currently I take the image out of the database, `base64_decode` it, and then replace all spaces with plusses to give:

```
data:image/png;base64,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...
```

I then use PHPMailers `AddStringAttachment`:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($base64image, "Something Something.png", "base64", "image/png")
```

This sends fine (There are other settings but they are not relevant). However, once I receive the email, it says that the file is corrupt. Does anyone know the correct routine for sending base64 images in PHPMailer?

## Edit 1

I removed all my modifications of the image, and am now sending it straight from the database. It comes out as:

```
ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9wbmc7YmFzZTY0LGlWQk9SdzBLR2dvQUFBQU5TVWhFVWdBQUFmRUFBQU96Q0FZQUFBQ29QVDh6QUFBQUFYTlNSMElBcnM0YzZRQUFBQVJuUVUxQkFBQ3hqd3Y4WVFVQUFBQUpjRWhaY3dBQURzTUFBQTdEQWNkdnFHUUFBUCBsU1VSQlZIaGU3UDNuYzEzWmRmYUw2bSA0WC9peDY5VDlvS3B6VDVVIGRwMTd6em45IHJVa0tsT3laYlV0eTJwbiB2VnJtYllsdXlWMWp1eEFFZ3dJQkFrU09lZEFCQUlnU0lKRUlnSXptTmxKVGNXbXVpVTFGZXd6N3ZPTXNjWmVjeSBzRFFJZ1dpM3FyTm4xMURObVdHRnZvdmR2anJuV1h2c2ovOHZYOTBpbVRKa3laY3FVNmY3UiBQaTQ2aU1mL1VhTFpNcVVLVk9tVEpudUg3M3h4aHVxai95dmp3NUtwa3laTW1YS2xPbiAwUzkgOFF2VlIvNC9qeDJSVEpreVpjcVVLZFA5by8vNnIvOVNmZVIvZS95b1pNcVVLVk9tVEpudUgzbkpJSjRwVTZaTW1UTGRaL0tTUVR4VHBreVpNbVc2eiBRbGczaW1USmt5WmNwMG44bExCdkZNbVRKbHlwVHBQcE9YRE9LWk1tWEtsQ25UZlNZdkdjUXpaY3FVS1ZPbSAweGVNb2hueXBRcFU2Wk05NW04WkJEUGxDbFRwa3laN2pONVdTWEViOG1OYU1QODhodDU2OGFic2psMUc1ZHYgd3ZwVE8xZnZmNjQvWHN5ODg0ZEdUIFUzcjlTZmZMUWogVEcgM3B5V3Q1OTU3YlVWS1dQVFZQbkQyMjdHM1BwOVhYVHRndFNjIFVYOHU2dmJmOHM3NzczTSBudlBwVSBQbE9tVEpreS9WN0t5enBCM01xUHJpeW1iUE5CNmFyTUtIaC9JelAzQXZGdGI4cGlBT...
```

This still gives an error when attempting to open.

## Resolution

```
$base = base64_decode($row['image']);
$resource = base64_decode(str_replace(" ", "+", substr($base, strpos($base, ","))));
$mail->addStringAttachment($resource, "Filename.png", "base64", "image/png");
```

Turns out I was only doing a single decode, when I needed to do 2 in order to get the binary data. Thank you to those who commented.

If you are attaching a file that was previously a data URI, posted directly from javascript as string for example, you maybe do not need to double-decode:

```
$base = $_POST['image'];
$resource = base64_decode(str_replace(" ", "+", substr($base, strpos($base, ","))));
$mail->addStringAttachment($resource, "Filename.png");
```

Comment: Whatever are you doing here? Don't mess with the image file. You can attach a raw image and send it. PHPMailer handles any required encoding for you.

Comment: My code around the image is: `$resource = str_replace(" ", "+", base64_decode($row['image']));`

Comment: Why are you doing that? Stripping 'spaces' out of binary data isn't going to end well. If the data is base-64 encoded in MySQL, you're doing it wrong - you should store straight binary without encoding.

Comment: @Synchro I upload the data using Javascript `FileReader.readAsDataURL(file)` via a POST request, I then store this in a blob, then pull it out.

Comment: Base64decode of base64 data of a binary image should be returning binary data, not more base64 data, so something isnt right here

Comment: You can easily spot real PNG data - bytes 2-4 of the data will contain 'PNG'.

Comment: Just this worked for me: 
    `$img = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $baseImage));` with your `$mail->AddStringAttachement($img, "Filename.png", "base64", "image/png");` Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I happened to have this issue now. Anyway, the solution is, if you [check the source code of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/b5845ebadae4a788152fadab8740d38fea18d2a5/class.phpmailer.php#L2865-L2898), it has stated clearly that, the first parameter of the function, is taking the **binary** data of the file.

Which means, to successfully send the image, if you already have the base64_encoded representation of your file, you should be just do `base64_decode` it without changing anything, and then pass it in. It should work.

You do not need to replace any strings from the long base64 encoded string. (Of course, decode it without the `data:image/png;base64,` heading texts).

Comment: String replace may be needed. It depends on your storage and transport engine. As such the strreplace was necessary for the existing system.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure why you will get spaces in the first place, probably transported through http, perhaps. Anyway, if it's pure base64 encoded, of course you do not need to replace anything. But since your base64 encoded string is not pure in a way that it has been altered, you will need to revert it back to the original value before sending it off.

Comment: If I recall correctly it was sent as a urlencoded base64 string, therefore the + became spaces. It was a fair while ago.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Was having the same issue hence found your question, and answered it anyway since I have it solved too :)